# Open source photo mosaic for web application

Tags: c#, jquery, html, css, image

I am looking for an open source tool to help me create mosaic images based on a series of given images. I've been searching the web but couldn't come up with anything web oriented solution.

Do you know any such tools?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Creating images is normally something you would do on the server side but this might come close to what you are looking for: http://ajaxian.com/archives/mosaic-image-builder-with-ajax

if you just want to show your images in an mosaic way you could use something like masonry: http://masonry.desandro.com/index.html

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you are looking for: http://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/39934
If you download the code and make a new refresh.jpg it should work. The code is written in processing which is very similar to java and can be run as an applet online if the user has java enabled in the browser.